# Using gradle convention plugin to set kotlin jvmTarget option

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Using a [Gradle convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) to share common configuration between subprojects, what is the correct way to set Kotlin compiler options, like `jvmTarget`?

This plugin setup results in a working build, but IntelliJ doesn't understand it, which leads me to think this isn't the correct approach:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // shared dependencies
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

This plugin is applied in subprojects like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'my.kotlin-conventions'
    id 'java-library'
}
```

I'm using Gradle 6.7, Kotlin 1.4.20.

---

*Edit: More info regarding IntelliJ problem*

In IntelliJ, in sub-projects, I am seeing the warning `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`. In the root project I don't see the warning, only in sub-projects. Building and running the project produces no problems (or warnings) at all.

Sample: https://github.com/nieldw/IntelliJ_Gradle_Convention_Plugin_Issue

Comment: How does “IntelliJ doesn't understand it” manifest itself? I believe I can change the JVM target with this approach just fine, incl. in IntelliJ. However, as you haven’t provided a [mcve], my setup might also differ …

Comment: @Chriki I've updated my question to explain the IntelliJ issue a bit more.

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Comment: Just thoughts. How about using gradle `allprojects` or `subprojects` dsl to apply plugins. I don't know if there is a difference between `plugins` sections in a multi-module project, but I remember we had the same issue with https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L12-L30

Comment: Thanks for the minimal reproducible example and for the error details! This was still a tricky one but I believe I’ve found a fix for your issue. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ seems to not like the `buildSrc/settings.gradle` file. When I remove it and “Reload All Gradle Projects”, then the errors that you’ve described disappear.

Commenting the `rootProject.name=…` line in the `buildSrc/settings.gradle` file works, too. Interestingly, uncommenting the line later (and reloading the Gradle configuration) is possible without breaking the IntelliJ configuration. So this should be your fix, I suppose.

Your build configuration looks correct to me. This rather sounds like a bug in IntelliJ’s Gradle support.

Comment: Hmm, yes probably a bug then. I had to also restart IJ before removing the `buildSrc/settings.gradle` file worked. Returning it (and restarting) didn't bring back the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Niel, glad to hear that it worked for you, too! If my answer was the solution to your problem, then I’d be happy if you could mark it as the accepted answer :o)

Comment: Hey @Chriki, you solution works, but I don't think it's the right solution. I awarded the bounty, but I'm hoping a more authoritative answer can be found.